# Copy a range of cells to a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a range of data (that is constantly being updated) to the next empty row in a different sheet for permanent storage. 
My code will work, but it will only copy the first row, I need it to copy a range of 9 rows. 
Thanks in advance!

```
Sub Export()

Dim Timestamp As Date
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim raw_data As Variant

'Records all data to DBO

Timestamp = Now
raw_data = Sheets("Data").Range("A2:M10").Value
        lastrow = Sheets("DBO").Range("B60000").End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets("DBO").Range("A" & lastrow + 1) = Timestamp
        Sheets("DBO").Range("B" & lastrow + 1, "N" & lastrow + 1).Value = raw_data
        Workbooks("Board.xlsm").Save

End Sub
```

Comment: change `"N" & lastrow + 1` to `"N" & lastrow + 9`

Comment: As simple as that... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
raw_data = Sheets("Data").Range("A2:M10").Value

With Sheets("DBO").Range("B60000").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).EntireRow

    .Cells(1).Value = Timestamp

    'If you set the destination range using the upper bounds of
    '   raw_data then you don't have to edit this line if you 
    '   change your input range from A2:M10 to something a different size
    .Cells(2).Resize(UBound(raw_data,1),UBound(raw_data,2)) = raw_data

End With

Workbooks("Board.xlsm").Save
```